# j2me zoom in zoom out in E-72

Tags: java-me, zooming, midlet

I want to do zoom in and zoom out in my j2me application. I am using a Nokia E-72. How can I do this?

Comment: What u want? tell me clearly. do u want to zoom the image or UI component?

Comment: when i am opening camera canvas at that time if user wants he can do zoom in and zoom out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to all J2ME Developer's

i found the solution for the problem.
As per [**this**](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Java_ME_API_support_on_Nokia_devices) link on nokia mobile using j2me doing zoom in and zoom out is not possible even you cant make any flash light even if phone supports flash light

so as a solution i found that calling a symbian application, which is having zoom in zoom out capability on phone camera even flash light facility.

for reference follow [**this**](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/J2ME_Api_Bridge_Interface) tutorial.

Its really nice working and acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

JSR 234 required for this purpose. 
See this [link...](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Series_40_6th_Edition%3a_Accessing_Camera_Capability_with_Advanced_Multimedia_Supplements_API_%28JSR-234%29) But i didnt use before and may be it helps you.. :)

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am using E-72 which is S60 device and document shows that it will work only on S40 6th Edition isn't it possible to do with E-72??

Comment: this is not working on nokia phones but working on sony's cybershot mobile, for camera purpose we need JSR-234 and as per this link http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Java_ME_API_support_on_Nokia_devices this is not possible with s60 only possible with s40's very selected model

Comment: try with my answer its really nice that way you can extend j2me capacity. i have tried and its working on my mobile